# Google Analytics is not showing screen name

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics

I'm using this package for setting up Google Analytics in my react native application. https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge

I follow it's tutorial, everything seems ok, but screen name.
As you see image below, My application has one user visiting, but on Page View area. It has nothing.
Google analytic real-time overview
When I check Acquisition -> Channels -> direct, I can see 5 pages having title, and one doesn't have (not set)
[Google analytics aquisition](https://ibb.co/mRWDKG)

This is my code (on App.js file):

```
import {
  GoogleAnalyticsTracker,
  GoogleTagManager,
  GoogleAnalyticsSettings
} from 'react-native-google-analytics-bridge'
import Config from 'react-native-config'
let tracker = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker(Config.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACK_ID)
tracker.trackScreenView('Home')

function getCurrentRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index]
  // dive into nested navigators

  if (route.routes) {
    return getCurrentRouteName(route)
  }
  return route.routeName
}

<RootNavigator
  onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
    const currentScreen = getCurrentRouteName(currentState)
    const prevScreen = getCurrentRouteName(prevState)
    if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
      tracker.trackScreenView(currentScreen)
    }
  }}
  ref={(navigatorRef) => {
    NavigatorService.setContainer(navigatorRef)
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

create a app in Google Analytic page. You will have a ID (as AU-...). After, you set this ID to GoogleAnalyticsTracker(ID)
Example:

```
let tracker = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker("AU-1234567");
```

And waiting about 15' after run app to app set to Google Analytic.

Comment: actually i had a tracking id for website beforehand. And as i see in logcat, everything seems ok. But i don't know why there is no data in page view area

Comment: when i work with Google Analytic, i still have a misstake. I'm not choose duration with today, so i can't anything in my page GA. Can you check it.